# How to override function only on specific object in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, overriding

Im getting familiar with Swift.

In obj-c, to add some touch functionality to UIScrollView I subclassed it and put this inside

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {
    return YES;
}
```

But in swift it's recommended to user protocols instead. If I use extensions, then this will become part of every UIScrollView on that view controller. I have two scrollviews on a screen and I want to add this only to one of them. How can I make an extension to only one scrollView?

Comment: You can subclass one of your scroll view and override this method in your subclass

Comment: You 'subclassed' the scrollview in objective-c .. the same will still work in swift.

Comment: ok, but as far as I read on the internet its recommended to reduce subclassing in Swift and try to find solutions through use of protocols and extensions.

Comment: I'll subclassed it, but still want to know if there is a better approach for swift. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom subclass of `UIScrollView`.  and override  `touchesShouldCancelInContentView` there

```
class YourClass: UIScrollView {

 override func touchesShouldCancelInContentView(view: UIView) -> Bool {

    return false
 }
}
```

Or if you want to give same class to both scrollview you  can create `@IBInspectable` property. it is also accessible from the identity inspector.

```
class MyScrollView: UIScrollView {

 @IBInspectable var touchCanceled: Bool = true

  override func touchesShouldCancelInContentView(view: UIView) -> Bool   {
    return self.touchCanceled
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From below steps you can over ride the particular method of particular class

```
// Step - 1 Write your custom class as below
class MyScrollView: UIScrollView {

    // Step - 2 Write method you want to override here. Ex. as below
    override init(frame: CGRect) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extensions and subclassing are not equal things. With extensions you can extend (add) new functions to an existing class or protocol.

In you case, you need to modify behaviour of a class, and in that case you need to do it by subclassing.

In your particular case, the only way is to subclass `UIScrollView` and override `touchesShouldCancel(in:)` (Swift 3):

```
override func touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

If you have just started learning about iOS and Swift, then it is also good to know about delegation pattern which is used a lot in iOS frameworks to reduce subclassing - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH11

Comment: Isn't it possible to override existing functions via extensions. Ok. i'll go with subclassing.

Comment: not in swift. And that would change the behaviour everywhere where the class is used. For example, if you change something in standard `UIScrollView`, then it will also be changed in table view and other places where it is used. In ObjC it would be possible by swizzling methods, but still, that would be more a hack rather than preferred design.